# Is semi-Lagrangian 1D advection identical to upwind Euler, when $|u|<\Delta x/\Delta t$?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, advection

This looked true to me, I worked through the algebra for 1D and confirmed it. But no one seems to mention it, so maybe I'm missing something...

I'm using Bridson's [SIGGRAPH 2007 course notes](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~rbridson/fluidsimulation/fluids_notes.pdf). [5MB pdf], p. 21 (page 33 in the pdf).

**Semi-Lagrangian**: back-trapolate the velocity field, to find the "particle" that would end up *here* ($x_i$), then linearly interpolate to get the value of that particle (pressure or whatever), which will become the value here ($q_i$).

Here, I assume velocity $u>0$ (to the right) and $\Delta t u < \Delta x$ (so the particle's previous position $x_P$ lies within the interval $[x_{i-1},x_i]$).

back-trapolate:
$$x_P = x_i - \Delta t u_i$$

interpolate:
$$\alpha = \frac{x_P - x_{i-1}}{\Delta x}$$

$$q_i^{t+1} = (1-\alpha)q_{i-1} + (\alpha)q_i$$

**Upwind Euler**
Choose forward or backward Euler, depending on the direction information is coming from, i.e. "upwind". This is stable, with my velocity restriction.

Reusing the above velocity restriction (to the right; moves less than a cell-width in a timestep).

$$q_i^{t+1} = q_i - \frac{\Delta t u_i(q_i - q_{i-1})}{\Delta x}$$

This is identical to the semi-Lagrangian above. (I won't go through all the algebra here, but I began by expanding the semi-Lagrangian into one line and used $x_i - x_{i-1} = \Delta x$).

They're also identical for $u<0$, just using the cell to the right i.e. $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ instead of $x_{i-1}$ and $x_i$.

---

Semi-Lagrangian advection enables jumping multiple cells (which I exclude with my velocity restriction), the only difference seems to be handling the velocity direction by determining which cell interval the particle lies in.

What am I missing? Perhaps higher-order "semi-Lagrangian" schemes don't correspond to upwind schemes so neatly?

Or maybe, jumping multiple cells is very useful sometimes? (In my case, I need the velocity restriction anyway).

I prefer upwind Euler, because it's simpler to calculate, less complex and easier to understand. But I've got into trouble before by "improving" schemes: my confidence exceeded my competence. So I'm checking this time.

Comment: I think there are major differences in 2d/3d. SL methods will involve corner cells also if the characteristic goes that way. Standard schemes use 1d stencils and corner cells are not involved. Of course there are special multi-d schemes which make use of corners also.

Comment: Semi-Lagrangian advection is popular especially in Computer Graphics, as it is unconditionally stable, even with a CFL larger than 1. My impression is that a CFL larger than 1 is quite common in CG.